# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{n} (\frac{x}{c})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{n} (\frac{x}{c})^n, c>0$

I have proved that this series converges pointwise on $[-c,c)$ by observing that for $x=-c$ the series is the alternating harmonic series, and for $x\in (-c,c)$ by using the root test. (Right?)

I have to prove uniform convergence on this interval as well. I have been looking for some sequence to compare with to use the Weierstrass M-test, but I haven't found anything useful. I'd love a hint or two. Thanks

Comment: Is this written as you intended?  Usually, $\frac 1{-n}$ would be written as $-\frac 1n$, or did you mean something else?

Comment: Why do you believe that the convergence is uniform on $[-c,c)$?

Comment: @lulu Yes it was intended that way, but I have changed it now so it looks better.

Comment: @Dr. Mv, Well I was asked to prove that it is

Comment: Uniform convergence on an interval $[-1+\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$ is by $M$ test.  So you only have to do $[-1,-1+\epsilon]$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks; But why on this particular interval? What sequence could I use for comparison?

Comment: You cannot prove uniform convergence, since the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I took $c=1$ and didn't tell you.

Comment: I guess that's why I was having a hard time proving it. Honestly, that TA and his exercises...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0<x<c$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac xc\right)^n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac xc\right)^n\right|&=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac xc\right)^n\\\\
&\ge \sum_{N+1}^{2N}\frac1n \left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^n\\\\
&\ge  \left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^{2N}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

By choosing $x=c\left(1-\frac{1}{2N}\right)$ in $(1)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac xc\right)^n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac xc\right)^n\right|&\ge \left(1-\frac{1}{2N}\right)^{2N}\\\\
&\ge \frac14
\end{align}$$

for $N\ge1$.  This negates uniform convergence for $x\in [-c,c)$.